# On Incoming Call when app is in background or app is not running the broadcast receiver is not called in Lenovo L18021(A5)

Tags: java, android

I am developing a custom dailer App incoming call screen but my problem is that when the app is in foreground, on incoming call the broadcast receiver is called and displays the custom screen but when the app is in the background or not in running state then the broadcast receiver is not called.
How to resolve this?

And Also Getting this Log

ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@3e5af9d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some devices (notably low-end and Chinese manufacture) apps are not permitted to perform background activities if they are not in a list of "protected apps". This is done to save battery life. If your device does this, it will not launch a `BroadcastReceiver` if the app is not already running. To fix this you will need to manually add your app to the list of "protected apps" or "apps allowed to perform background activities". There is a setting in the Android settings for the user to maintain this list of apps. It is usually in the "Security" or "Power management" settings somewhere.

Comment: but how  manage truecaller and other app in this phone

Comment: Those apps are probably already in this list. The manufacturers automatically add some apps and some apps tell their users to add the app to the list.

Comment: How to resolve this issue can you please help me

Comment: You need to verify that this is the problem. Have you verified that this is the problem? Have you found the settings page and added your app to the list of protected apps? Did it solve the problem? If this is the problem then you need to tell your users to add your app to the list of protected apps. There is nothing else you can do.

Comment: thanku so much @David after adding  list of protected apps working fine

Comment: Super. If my answer was helpful to you, you should click the green checkmark next to my answer. This will give me some reputation points, will increase your "acceptance rate" and also help any other developers who have a similar problem. I hope you find Stackoverflow useful in the future!